# Macbooks randomly disconnecting from wifi about twice a day

Tags: wireless

I kind of placed into a network admin position due to my proximity of the hardware and very slight knowledge of the subject at a growing company. One of our offices is in a super crowded area and all our neighbors seem to have their own wifi + broadcasting a wonderful xfinity signal as well. I'm guessing this is my main issue, but all our macbooks seem to randomly disconnect once or twice a day. It happens for about a minute, and sometimes requires turning the wireless on the mac off and on.

I've got a sonicwall and a couple of ruckus r610s. I previously had some ubiquiti WAPs in there but replaced them hoping the ruckus waps would perform better (they haven't so far...). Anyone have any advice or experience with something similar?

Things ive tried: Running new cable, replacing WAPs, trying different channels on waps, trying different ruckus firmware, manually setting MTU on mac.

Things I should probably try: Going to each of our 20~ neighbors and asking them to turn off their xfinity wifi.

Comment: Your question is really too broad to answer, lacking in any specifics, and all we could do is speculate or guess, which is off0topic here. Please review the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question to include enough information.